# iPython notebook automatically creates new empty notebooks

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am just starting with iPython notebook --pylab inline.  It works great for what I am doing.  I am happily creating multiple notebooks for different areas that I am working on.  However, on the first launch page in my browser (the one that lists all of the notebooks), I keep seeing new Unknown* notebooks appearing over time.  The respective Uknown*.ipynb files appear next to my notebooks on the file system as well. I can easily click 'Shutdown' and 'Delete' to eliminate these with no adverse effects.

Why do these notebooks keep appearing?  Can I stop them from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

They should not appear unless you explicitly create them. Are you by any chance renaming the notebook manually on the filesystem ?

Comment: No, I'm not.  They don't show up very quickly.  Just one ever few hours.  No clue why.

Comment: This is strange, which browser/ipython version/os ? Any chance of something pinging https://url-to-notebook/new , like a thumbnail extension for links ?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.8.4.  Safari 6.0.5.  ipython 0.13.2.  Python 2.7.5.  I'm mostly using numpy, scipy, nltk, matplotlib, and scikit-learn.  I have been creating new notebooks manually from the dashboard.  I click 'New Notebook' and I rename the notebook by clicking the name at the top on the new web page.  As I said, I'm new to this so maybe that's the wrong workflow?

Comment: Everything seem normal to me. you could try runnig with `--debug` flag, to find out when those notebook are created ? Can't give you exactly what to look for I'm on 1.0.dev. Try correlate with things like browsing history on safari (which definitively create thumbnail of http://localhost/new which create new notebook.)

Comment: I may have figured it out.  I think it has to do with a behavior of Safari that is rebuilding a cache of recently visited pages.  After enough time it stops happening.  I'm looking to see if there is a way to make it stop (other than just switching to Chrome or Firefox).

Comment: Ok, great, I opened an issue on IPython side to see if we can do something. As if we do it, it will break api, it won't happend soon.